# Can I call a timeout function on the returned element in this if statement?

Tags: javascript

Can I call a timeout function on the returned element in this if statement?

```
var data = 'some stuff';

if(data){
  return jQuery('<div class="thisDiv"></div>').html(data);  
}
```

I've tried the following:

```
if(data){
    setTimeout(function() {
        return jQuery('<div class="thisDiv"></div>').html(data); 
    }, 100);
}
```

But I get this error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined
```

Comment: Is there more code than this?  You have a return statement that isn't inside a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You cannot use `setTimeout` to delay when a function will return. It is not a sleep function. It puts a function on a queue to run later, it doesn't stop all processing for a period of time.

```
function a() {
    return 1;
}

var x = a();
```

In the above you have a single function which has a return statement. The value it returns is assigned to `x`.

```
function b() {
    setTimeout(function c() {
        return 1;
    }, 1000);
}

var y = b();
```

Now you have two functions. `b` has no return statement, so it returns `undefined` and `undefined` is stored in `y`.

`b` uses `setTimeout` to call `c`, and `c` has a return statement. `setTimeout` doesn't do anything with return values though, so the return value of `c` is discarded.

---

Any time you are dealing with asynchronous functions, you have to do something with the data inside the asynchronous callback (such as call another function and pass the data as an argument). There is no going back, it is too late for that.

You could return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from `b` though. That would allow other code to use the value of `y` to bind event handlers that will fire when the timeout expires.

Answer (score 3):

The `return` statement will return from the anonymous function you passed into the `setTimeout` function, not the function enclosing the scope of the `if` statement. Try passing a callback into the function containing the `if` statement, then calling that callback with the `data` as a parameter.

```
function delayedReturn(callback) {
  if(data) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      callback(jQuery('<div class="thisDiv"></div>').html(data)); 
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can, you'd need to remove the `return` and use a valid selector to target your div.

Something like this would work:

### HTML

```
<div class="thisDiv">test</div>
```

### Javascript:

```
var data = 'some stuff';

if(data){
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('.thisDiv').html(data); 
    }, 100);
}
```

You can see it working here:  https://jsfiddle.net/ckkz1wbf/

Answer (score 1):

Question, Why are you using:

```
jQuery('<div class="thisDiv"></div>')
```

Are you try to create an element, if that the case, you could use delay from jquery.

```
function fn(){
    var data = 'some stuff';
    if(data){
        return jQuery('<div class="thisDiv"></div>').delay(100).html(data);
    }
}
```